# Bash - Without check if command exist different result with and without sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have this test.sh script:

```
if tesseract --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

If I execute `./test.sh` , it prints Found, but if I execute it with sudo `sudo ./test.sh`, then it says that is Not found.
Any help? :)

Comment: Perhaps the command isn't found in sudo's path? Check out `sudo visudo` and insure that the path to your command exists in the `secure_path` line.

Comment: also prefer using `if command -v tesseract >/dev/null` so as not to execute a command if you only want to test for availability and or path with: `if tesseract_path="$(command -v tesseract)"; then echo "found $tesseract_path"; fi`